# How to build a recursive tree in Java-ee?

Tags: jakarta-ee, concurrency, managedthreadfactory

Here is my pseudo-code:

```
class Builder implements Callable<T> {
  T obj;
  ManagedExecutorService pool;

  Builder (T obj, ManagedExecutorService pool){
    this.obj = obj;
    this.pool = pool;
  }

  T call(){
    build();
  }

  private void build(){
        // skip if already traversed
        return isTraversed(obj);

        // call db and get obj's one-to-many relationships
        Collection<T> colOfChildObj = DbUtil.getChildrenPOJO(obj);
        for (<Collection>T childObj : colOfChildObj){
            this.pool.submit(new Builder(childObj, this.pool));
        }
        // set children as-is, when the submit above completes,
        // it will update childObj and thus will reflect
        // obj.childObj.itsChidren etc. For this though the caller
        // has to wait until all submits are processed 
        obj.setChildren(colOfChildObj); 
  }
}
```

Since Java-ee does not support ForkJoinPool - that is out of the question. So how do I do it with either ManagedThreadFactory and/or ManagedExecutorService? My real challenge is due to not being able to call pool.shutdown() or pool.awaitTermination in Java-ee. So, from the caller, if I do:

```
class Caller () {
  T getObjGraph(T rootObj){
     pool.submit(new Builder(rootObj));
     T objGraph = pool.get();
     return objGraph;
  }
}
```

Then my method does not wait for all the pool.submit(new Builder(childObj, pool)) and thus my object does not have everything set and is incomplete. I thought of putting all Futures returned by pool.submit into a blocking queue - but then I don't know how to inform the caller that my tree traversal is complete. I do have a counter that reaches 0 when the tree traversal is complete but since the client is submitting a top level node, I'm not sure how to make it wait there in Java-ee without while(isCounter = 0) - which is a CPU hog.

Any pointers?

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve? The title suggests you're trying to build a tree. But the question suggests you're trying to do something (but what?) concurrently. What are you trying to achieve? It seems you're trying to deal with managed JPA entities from multiple threads. This, already, is wrong: managed entities are not thread-safe. They're linked to a persistence context that is not thread-safe.

Comment: See my updates with additional details. No these are not Managed objects - just POJOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. You can just use a thread-safe counter, increment it every time you create and submit a new task for a given node, and decrement it when the task for this node is terminated.

In the main thread, you wait on a lock util the remaining number of nodes to process is 0. And in each task, you notify the lock to signal that a tack is terminated.

Here is a complete example. It starts from a tree where each node has a name, and transforms this tree into another tree where each node is "Hello " concatenated with the original name.

```
public class Tree {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Node root = new Node("R");

        Node c1 = new Node("C1");
        Node c2 = new Node("C2");

        root.addChild(c1);
        root.addChild(c2);

        Node gc11 = new Node("GC11");
        Node gc12 = new Node("GC12");
        c1.addChild(gc11);
        c1.addChild(gc12);

        Node gc21 = new Node("GC11");
        Node gc22 = new Node("GC12");
        c2.addChild(gc21);
        c2.addChild(gc22);

        System.out.println("root = " + root);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        final Object lock = new Object();
        final AtomicInteger remaining = new AtomicInteger(0);
        Future<Node> result = executor.submit(new HelloTask(root, null, executor, remaining, lock));

        synchronized (lock) {
            while (remaining.get() != 0) {
                lock.wait();
            }
        }

        Node helloRoot = result.get();

        System.out.println("helloRoot = " + helloRoot);

        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static class HelloTask implements Callable<Node> {
        private final Node source;
        private final Node parent;
        private final ExecutorService executorService;
        private final Object lock;
        private final AtomicInteger remaining;

        public HelloTask(Node source, Node parent, ExecutorService executorService, AtomicInteger remaining, Object lock) {
            this.source = source;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.executorService = executorService;
            this.lock = lock;
            this.remaining = remaining;
            remaining.incrementAndGet();
        }

        @Override
        public Node call() throws Exception {
            // simulate some time
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            Node result = new Node("Hello " + source.getName());
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.addChild(result);
            }
            for (Node child : source.getChildren()) {
                executorService.submit(new HelloTask(child, result, executorService, remaining, lock));
            }

            remaining.decrementAndGet();
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static class Node {
        private final String name;
        private final List<Node> children = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

        public Node(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public List<Node> getChildren() {
            return children;
        }

        public void addChild(Node child) {
            this.children.add(child);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(name);
            sb.append('\n');
            children.forEach(sb::append);
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - you understand it correctly. Only thing is I need this to run in java-ee container so per the spec I can't invoke lock.wait() or lock.notifyAll() operations. Also I cannot do  executor.shutdown(); - which I guess is irrelevant with the synchronized(lock) loop. Is there a way this can be wrapped into a Future somehow? So instead of synchronized(lock), do result.get() - which in turn would resolve the tree-traverse completion?

Comment: The shutdown here is just there to avoid the command-line demo to run endlessly. You wouldn't use it on your server. I think you're reading the spec too cautiously: calling wait() and notify() in this way is not a problem. Not more than for example, sending an HTTP request synchronously, and thus blocking until the response comes back.

Comment: You can't just do result.get(), because that would return as soon as the root node has been processed, and while the child nodes are still being processed.

Comment: Just want to add that in java-ee environment I had to use: new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue, getThreadFactory()) - so that recursion being of unknown depth does not exhaust on threads (and instead keeps adding tasks to the non-blocking queue)...